# Disallow <!ELEMENT> and other declarations in schemas (DTD, XSD)?

Tags: xml, security, xsd, xsd-validation, dtd

Is there a way to use a schema (preferably XSD) to let validation of an XML document fail, if there are `<!ELEMENT ...>` and similar declarations contained?

Or would the XML parser still be vulnerable and eventually crash?

http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/xml-vulnerabilities/

**Example:** Billion laughes

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE lolz [
<!ENTITY lol "lol">
<!ENTITY lol2 "&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;">
<!ENTITY lol3 "&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;">
<!ENTITY lol4 "&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;">
<!ENTITY lol5 "&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;">
<!ENTITY lol6 "&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;">
<!ENTITY lol7 "&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;">
<!ENTITY lol8 "&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;">
<!ENTITY lol9 "&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;">
]>
<lolz>&lol9;</lolz>
```

`&lol9;` is parsed and expanded to 10x `&lol8;` and so on, ending up with creating 1,000,000,000 `lol` entities and probably make the XML parser run out of memory.

Can any of the listed vulnerabilities be exploited in **MSXML 6.0**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, XSD constrains the infoset of the parsed XML document; any DTD processing is logically prior to XSD validation, and XSD has no way to require, allow, or forbid the presence or absence of a DTD.

I believe some XML parsers have invocation options to bound their resource usage; even if the parser doesn't have that option, the operating system normally does.

Comment: Some parsers seem to have proprietary options to disallow inline DTD declarations, probably the only safe way to secure the host environment.